# Python script for autoclicking and downloading

Tags: python

Can you help me with a script for autoclicking and download a photo from a photo site (ex. Flickr, Photobucket)?

Comment: If you haven't started, look into selenium maybe. It allows you to click things on given websites and automatically download stuff.

Comment: python has no built-in functionality for that. you need some library that supports doing this either on your OS level or in your browser (like selenium)

Answer (score 1):

selenium, find **elementByName**, then use **pynput** lib to right click and download.
used similar for fetching market data works prety well, refer to official selenium docs for spesifics .